# Upload File restriction in PHP

Tags: php

I have an application where user can upload files , its base on PHP File Upload ..

we have limit of max 10 files can be uploaded at once . what i need server side validation script in case user can uploaded more than 10 file , application should be prevent same ..

I tried below code

```
$max_file_upload = 10;


if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
      $num = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
      if ($num > $max_file_upload){
      $errormsg = "HTTPS PROCESS: - File limit is Over";
      return $message;
      exit;
      }
    }
```

But some how its not working  .. can you Please guide me how i do that ..

Comment: I hope the HTML line looks this for the uploading the file!!                                       <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" id="file" multiple />

Comment: " $message" is not defined in the above script

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is in variable $errormsg but you are returning variable $message. 
Use the below code,

```
$max_file_upload = 10;


if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
      $num = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
      if ($num > $max_file_upload){
      $errormsg = "HTTPS PROCESS: - File limit is Over";
      echo $errormsg;
      exit;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix here:

```
$max_file_upload = 10;

if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
      $num = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
      if ($num > $max_file_upload){
       $errormsg = "HTTPS PROCESS: - File limit is Over";
       return $errormsg;
      }
    }
```